# Clone USB flash drive containing UDF and Fat32 paritions

Tags: usb, udf

Recently I was asked to clone USB flash drive (4GB). This drive contains two paritions: first is UDF (1.3GB) - which Windows 7 sees as CD-ROM drive, and the second is Fat32(2.7GB) - which looks and behaves like a normal removable device. When I open Windows Disk Management it shows two separate devices - CD-ROM and removable device with one Fat32 partition.

I need tool that will make full image of entire flash drive and will be also able to write that image to another flash drive.

I tried USB tools: 
Passmark ImageUSB / RMPrepUSB - but they can only see partition with Fat32.

I also tried some backup tools:
Macrium Reflect Free / Paragon Backup And Recovery / DriveImage XL - they see physical disk of size 2.7GB with only one Fat32 partition - which is also wrong.

Can you recommend me any Windows / Linux tool that would allow me to clone this USB drive?

Answer (score 0):

[Win32DiskImager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/files/Archive/) will let you make an exact byte-to-byte copy of any removable storage (on Windows). The only problem is: you won't be able to restore to smaller drives, they have to be at least as big as source disk.

`dd` is a command line equivalent for Linux/*NIX systems, you can use it like this:

```
dd if=/dev/name_of_device of=name_of_output_file bs=4K
```